# Sorting YUI Datatable, keep null values on Top

Tags: yui, yui-datatable

I am sorting a YUI Datatable, with a column as Date, there are some NULL values for the column.

I need to have those null values remain on top rows of the table, irrespective of the sort order.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a custom sorting function.

Comment: can you please help me with that...i am not sure how to do it

Answer (score 0):

@chittprakash

Here is an example : http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/DataTable.Sortable.html